# css event class jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am generating the html table dynamically using javascript.
     Adding the button for each row and a css class for that, the onlick event for that css class is not getting called. Need a help where I am making a mistaking.

```
Here is my code for reference

for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
$("#desgtable").append("<tr rowindex='Number(i+1)'><td>"+i+"</td><td><input type='button' class='case' </td></tr>");

 }


 $(".case").click(function(){
     alert();
}
```

Comment: use event delegation. $("#desgtable").on("click",".case",function(){});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event delegation:

```
 $(document).on('click',".case",function(){
     alert();
});
```